# Java copy section of array

Tags: java, arrays, copy, java1.4

Is there a method that will copy a section of an array(not arraylist) and make a new array from it?

```
Example:
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and you create a new array from it:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Are there any one line/methods that will do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a java 1.4 compatible 1.5-liner:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int size = 3;

int[] part = new int[size];
System.arraycopy(array, 0, part, 0, size);
```

You could do this in one line, but you wouldn't have a reference to the result.

To make a one-liner, you could refactor this into a method:

```
private static int[] partArray(int[] array, int size) {
    int[] part = new int[size];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, part, 0, size);
    return part;
}
```

then call like this:

```
int[] part = partArray(array, 3);
```

Answer (score 26):

See the method [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-)

Answer (score 9):

There is a pre-existing method in the `java.util.Arrays`: `newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(myArray, startindex, endindex)`. Or you could easily write your own method:

```
public static array[] copyOfRange(array[] myarray, int from, int to) {
    array[] newarray = new array[to - from];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < to - from ; i++) newarray[i] = myarray[i + from];
    return newarray;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int [] myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

int [] holder = new int[size];

System.arraycopy(myArray,0,holder,size);
```

where 0 stands for the index of source array from where copying should start.
and

size stands for the number of copy operations. That you can changes according to your need.

copyOfRange of Arrays is there 
and many other ways by which this can be accomplished

Comment: You're missing one argument for it requires another int for destinationPosition.

Answer (score 5):

[Arrays#copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

As others have stated, you can use Arrays.copyOfRange method. An example is :

```
String[] main = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
int from = 2;
int to = 4;
String[] part = Arrays.copyOfRange(main, from, to);
```

Now **part** will be : **{"two", "three", "four"**}

Comment: There is an error, part is ``{"three", "four", "five"}``, because arrays index starts at 0